# Drools Version 7.52 not using GDST Hit Policy

Tags: drools

My Drools project has a number of GDSTs (Guided Decision Tables); those tables were created in the JBPM Workbench with hit policies of either 'First Hit' or 'Rule Order'. After upgrading from version 7.39 to 7.52 those policies are no longer being used. This is causing a lot of infinite loops.

Is there anyway to debug why this might be happening?

I will continue recompiling my projects at different version levels, 7.39, 7.40, etc; to try and determine where the support for Hit Policies stopped working but for now I was wondering if anyone else had experienced this issue and how they resolved it.

I am working on creating some JBPM objects that I can post, my actual project has data that I can not share. The additional details should be ready in a few hours. Sorry jumped the gun when posting the question, I know it needs more details, pom files at the very least.

**Update Jun 8, 2021**
First a quick background:
I am using the JBPM-Server Ver 7.52 that you can download from Drools website. Simply run the standalone.sh and you will have access to the Business Central Workbench.

Once in the Workbench I created some data objects and a few GDST's. The GDST's are created with Hit Policies of either 'First Hit' or 'Rule Order'. Also, when updating a field on the data object I am setting the 'Update Engine' option.

After the Workbench project has been created I can download the KJAR artifact and use it as a dependency in a Java API that pulls in data, loads the KieSession with rules from the artifact and data, executes the rules and processes the responses.

I know that the 'Update Engine' option, in combination with the loss of support for the Hit Policies, is causing the infinite loops.

I have also determined that this stopped working at version 7.52, everything works perfectly from versions 7.39 all the way through 7.51.

The only difference I have found between the two versions is that at 7.52 the 'source' for the GDST is now adding an activation-group parameter related the hit policy.